# VGG Input not defined

Tags: python, vgg-net

I am running the code below to load a VGG 16 model but the i keep getting an error Input not defined. Any ideas please?

```
# load model and specify a new input shape for images and avg pooling output
new_input = Input(shape=(640, 480, 3))
model = VGG16(include_top=False, input_tensor=new_input, pooling='avg')
```

Error Message
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
 in 
      1 # load model and specify a new input shape for images and avg pooling output
----> 2 new_input = Input(shape=(640, 480, 3))
      3 model = VGG16(include_top=False, input_tensor=new_input, pooling='avg')

NameError: name 'Input' is not defined

Comment: did you import the input layer from keras? `from keras.layers import Input`? (assuming youre using keras)

Answer (score 0):

You need to import Input from keras.layers.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

`from tensorflow.keras.layers import Input`